# Pintar Datos De LocalStorage Angular

Tags: angular

Quiero pintar en un CARD los datos del usuario logueado

FUNCION PARA OBTENER TOKEN

```
export class Page1Component implements OnInit {

 constructor(private router: Router , private service : UserService ,) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  var User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Token'));
  console.log(User);

  }
```

Y Aqui es donde quiero que me pinte

```html
<div class="card m-5" style="width: 18rem" >

  <div class="card-body">
    <span>{{User.usuarioID}}</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: desde la variable token puedes acceder a usuarioId y las demas propiedades no?

Comment: Si bro desde esa variable puedo obtener todo, pero necesito pintarlo en el card

Comment: crea en el ts una variable global al ts , llamala en el html y en el ngOninit l4 asiganas JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Token')); a la variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia a esto:

```
export class FormularioReactivoComponent implements OnInit {
user: any;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Token'));
}
}
```

Sucede que estas creando una variable con "var" dentro del ngOnInit por lo que al resolverse este ciclo de vida tu variable desaparece. Necesitas crear una variable para toda la clase y esta es la que va poder mostrarse en el HTML.

Answer (score 1):

en angular, en  tu componente actual crea una variable llamada **User**

```
var User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Token'));
```

ahora ya tienes la variable User que puedes usar en el html

tal como esta en tu ejemplo

```
<span>{{User.usuarioID}}</span>
```

Comment: Pero debo colocar algo como ngif o ngfor ?=

Comment: por estandar no es mejor llamar a la variable con un nombre en minuscula?

Comment: @KristianEspitia puedes poner el codigo del ts y el html ?

Comment: Ya edite el codigo Esta el TS y el html

Comment: @KristianEspitia tienes que declarar user afuera del metodo ngOninit , public user; y en el ngOninit this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Token'));

Comment: OHhhhh si bro funciono Te doy un like que pro eres

Comment: @KristianEspitia SI TE SOLUCIONO MI RESPUESTA DEBERIAS DAR +1 O MARCAR COMO CORRECTA MI RESPUESTA